# Making a new post visible on a specific page

Tags: posts, menus, pages

I am creating a wordpress site which will have different sections , which will essentially be pages which can be accessed through a top level menu. Now when I make a post, I dont necessarily want all the posts to appear on the front page but instead while making the post want to choose which page it should be shown in. I cannot find a way to do this in wordpress 3.x. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this using the plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/).

1) create an ACF item with the following config
[image]
<sup>[view larger](http://cl.ly/3m0t1M2C3E3v090D0931)</sup>

2) it will show a metabox when editing a Post, where you can select which Page the post should appear

[image: metabox example]

3) in your page template, adapt this code to your needs

```
<?php
// START - THE LOOP
$the_ID = $post->ID;

$search_posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key' => 'show_this_post_on_page'
));
if($search_posts) {
    foreach($search_posts as $post_found) {
        $key_value = get_post_meta($post_found->ID, 'show_this_post_on_page', true);
        foreach($key_value as $key => $value) {
            if($value==$the_ID) echo 'The post <strong>'.$post_found->post_title.'</strong> should appear in this page';
        }
    }
}
// END - THE LOOP
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How many of those pages you have? There are lots of way you can do this.

1. Normally you can do it via making specific category for each pages.
2. If you don't want to make extra category for this reason you can make tags for it.
3. If you want to make some post that will show in homepage. You can use the `post_thumbnail()` feature and make query in homepage for posts which have post thumbnails only.
4. Or you can use custom post types is special cases.

Comment: Can you please point me to some of the plugins that would help me do this ?

Comment: Can't really help you with this if you not coding :) i am not really know this kinds of plugins really well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Wordpress code, then you can assign a category or tag to that post then use custom queries on the pages you want to show or hide the tag in and put something like

```
$query = new WP_Query('category__in=mytag');     
//or 
$query = new WP_Query('category__not_in=23');
```

You may want to read [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) in wordpress codex.

Answer (score 0):

If the posts don't have any similarities, you could manually add them to each page you want using the [Inline Posts Plugin](http://aralbalkan.com/1016).